# Transfer a df to a new one and change the context of a column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have one dataframe **df_test** and I want to parse **all** the columns into a new df.
Also I want with if else statement to modify one column's context.

Tried this:

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df_cast= df_test.withColumn('account_id', when(col("account_id") == 8, "teo").when(col("account_id") == 9, "liza").otherwise(' '))
```

But it gives me this error:

**NameError:** name 'when' is not defined

Thanks in advance

Comment: use numpy, more exaclty numpy.where to change the value of the column

Comment: numpy.where is not related to pyspark. Use pyspark.sql.functions.when instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of your code, you should import the pyspark sql functions. The following, for example, would work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df_cast= df_test.withColumn('account_id', F.when(col("account_id") == 8, "teo").F.when(col("account_id") == 9, "liza").otherwise(' '))
```